# Pending Tasks and Protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, automated-tests

I am trying to use Protractor to test my teams new Angular site. Currently, the Protractor project is not located locally, but in a different repo, separate from the Angular code. The login page is not angular so we run `waitForAngularEnabled(false)` for the login page, but once we login we run `waitForAngularEnabled(true)`.

Unfortunately, the test ends up hanging and does not continue because it hits a timeout. This is the stacktrace...[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14PBl.png)

I read a little about Protractor's execution and it waits for pending tasks to be resolved. When I run `getAllAngularTestabilities()` in the devtools console, it shows that there is a pending macrotask. Is that why my test hangs after the `waitForAngularEnabled(true)`? Here is a picture of the devtools console...[devtools console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cot56.png)

If I don't use `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` then I will have to use explicit sleeps. I want to be able to run that and have the test running like normal.

Here is the test file code, login.ts. The 'beforeEach' block handles the non angular login and the 'it' block handles the rest of the test.

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { LoginPage } from '../pageobjects/LoginPage';
import { SelectOrgPage } from '../pageobjects/SelectOrgPage';
import { MainPage } from '../pageobjects/MainPage';

describe('Login', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // Make sure to set the ignoreSynchronization for every testrun
    // for non Angular applications
    // browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    
    await browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    const loginPage = new LoginPage();
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    await loginPage.open(site-address);
    await loginPage.typeIntoEmailAddressInput(Email);
    await loginPage.typeIntoPasswordInput(Password);
    await loginPage.clickSigninBtn();
    await browser.sleep(5000);
  });

  it('go to resources', async () => {

    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
    
    // await browser.refresh();
    // await browser.sleep(10000);

    const mainPage = new MainPage();
    await mainPage.clickResourcesTab();
    await mainPage.clickCropsSideNav();

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the reason 100%, however I'm not sure what's causing `hasPendingMicroTasks` to be true. So I'm just continuing working with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`

Comment: In doing that, are you getting the full benefits of protractor?

Comment: well you lose a bit on built in waiting... but if the app is built right, it'll always have a loading animation up if there is something to wait for. This way all I do is write `wait until no loading animation is in the DOM`

Comment: Did you ever try to figure out what the pending task was? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Your Protractor communicates with Angular, it uses the Angular Testability API, the API returns a variable called is_stable. When this variable is true, it means that your Angular website is stable. Which means that all the promises in your page has been resolved and there are no active processes that the page is waiting for finish.

One solution can be running all async tasks out side angular zone i.e. you can use `NgZone` for this purpose. `ngZong.runOutsideAngular();`.

Comment: Yeah, the is_stable variable is true. Does that mean its not waiting for the pending 'macrotask' and the issue is something else?

Comment: Is there any third party integration in your app?

Comment: I believe we use Auth0 for the login, but that is it I believe.

Comment: I am not sure but i guess you should use `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` in login.ts file in `afterAll` function. Hope it will work